# How to open multiple chat forms with users separately, but block opening forms which already have been opened?

Tags: c#, winforms

**Prelude**

At first, sorry for my bad english. :)

I read a tone of similar questions on SO, but none of them provide a solution for my problem, or I'm just stupid. :)

**Question**

How would I open a new chat form to talk with `User1` and retain the possibility to open chat forms with other users from "users list", but block opening a chat form with a user which is already open?

I tried to find something for this, but whatever I tried, it always is same (I can open same form again and again).

So, for example, I can open a chat form with `User1`, I can talk with him, and I can also open a new chat form with `User2` and I can talk with him. But I can also open multiple forms with User1, and with User2 to, etc.

Also, I need to pass some data from `MainForm` form to `TalkForm`, so as prototype I created this code and I tried to list, but I'm not sure how to check if a form does exist in the list:

```
List<TalkForm> b = new List<TalkForm>();
    private void TextBoxConnectedClients_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBoxConnectedClients.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            return;
        }
        int index = this.TextBoxConnectedClients.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
        if (index != System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NoMatches)
        {
            string username = TextBoxConnectedClients.SelectedItem.ToString();
            TalkForm a = new TalkForm(im, username, displayname);
            b.Add(a);
            a.Show();
        }
    }
```

Can someone please give me some examples or tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<TalkForm> b = new List<TalkForm>();
```

You are using this list to track the forms opened for each unique user. I would update your code to check if form object is already added. You need to add `using System.Linq`

```
if (index != System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NoMatches)
{
    string username = TextBoxConnectedClients.SelectedItem.ToString();

    // Check if form is already opened. Username will be unique.
    var form = b.firstOrDefault(f => f.Username == username);
    if (form == null)  // Show new form
    {
        TalkForm a = new TalkForm(im, username, displayname);
        b.Add(a);
        a.Show();
    }
    else // Activate already opened form
    {
        form.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

You need to expose `TalkForm.Username` property, if it's not in place already. And initialize that property in the constructor with `username` parameter.

Note: Make sure you `Remove` the form instance from list `b` when close a form for specific user.

**Edit**: Updated code to show already opened form as per @Draken's suggestion.

Comment: Got this error:

`"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'"`

`Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not 
implicitly convertible to the delegate return type"`

Comment: My bad. Single '=' comparison was a culprit. Update the code above.

Comment: You can also add an else statement to this and instead call the current chat window to the front, if one already exists, using the [`Control.BringToFront`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx):
`TalkForm form = b.firstOrDefault(t=> t.Username == username); if (form != null) {form;BringToFront();}`

Comment: Nice suggestion @Draken. Updating answer with Credit to you.

Comment: @nikhivartak i notice '=' after posting the error, it works.Thank you guys.